# want to create a link in email that will post custom/specific text from email to facebook

Tags: email, facebook-opengraph

I have a concierge service that my customers use to ask all sorts of questions. Many of them get their answers emailed to them. A number of them have asked if we could add a button in the email body that will allow them to post the contents of the question/answer to facebook.

I have researched this for a while, specifically the facebook developer tutorial on Open Graph, but it seems that I will be limited to creating very narrow sentences with predefined objects and actions.

So for example, let's say a customer of mine has the following answer emailed to them:

***begin email***

question: What were the 3 highest scores in NFL history?

answer: The Washington Redskins beat the New York Giants 72–41, November 27, 1966.

The Cincinnati Bengals beat the Cleveland Browns 58–48, November 28, 2004.

The Oakland Raiders beat the Houston Oilers (now the Tennessee Titans) 52-49, December 22, 1963.

[ post to facebook ]

***end email***

What I want to happen is that when the user clicks on the "post to facebook" link in the email, it will post the following on their facebook account:

***begin facebook post***

John Smith asked xxxx Concierge a question.

question: What were the 3 highest scores in NFL history?

answer: The Washington Redskins beat the New York Giants 72–41, November 27, 1966.

The Cincinnati Bengals beat the Cleveland Browns 58–48, November 28, 2004.

The Oakland Raiders beat the Houston Oilers (now the Tennessee Titans) 52-49, December 22, 1963.

***end facebook post***

Does facebook make such an automated post (linked to from an email) possible?

Thanks.